# Create an array of all jpeg files start with 'n' - PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I would like to create an array of all files in a directory which start with the letter 'n' and are image files of the jpg or JPEG. My code so far is:

```
//Get all the files in the products images directory
if ($dir = opendir($uploads)) {
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {                  
            foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename { 
            $images[] = $filename;
            } 
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

I have tried by adding in the foreach, but it is causing a 500 server error. I'm new to coding in php, so any advice would be most appreciated.
Regards

Donna

Comment: Someone recently pointed out that whenever you've got a 500 you **must** start with checking out your webserver's logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: rewritten, tested. Works fine, no matter if your file are named with lowercase or uppercase.

Please notice that you have to set the variable `$uploads` with slash at the end.

```
$uploads = 'uploads/'; // must be with slash at the end

if ($dir = opendir($uploads))
{
  $images = array();

  foreach (glob($uploads."*.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename)
  {
    $f = str_replace($uploads, null, $filename);
    if (strtolower($f[0]) == 'n')
    {
      $images[] = $f;
    }
  }
}    

echo '<pre>';
print_r($images);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you, do you by anychance have an idea how i can create a list of the filenames rather than an array of the images themselves?

Comment: Ok im getting somewhere, if i echo $file before the foreach loop, i get a page full of filenames, however the $filename echo is not producing anything? Any additional ideas as to what might be wrong?

Comment: When you echo `$file` before `foreach()` then you get a list of all files in the folder.
instead of 
`if ($filename[0] == 'n')`

try this:
`if(substr($filename, 0, 1) == 'n')`

I understand that all your files contains lowercase "n", not starting with "N".

Comment: still nothing i am afraid, even if i try and echo the $filename before the code with the 'n' in it nothing is displayed. I don't think the filenames are being logged?

Comment: Give 30-40 mins.  I will test it on my ownown.

Comment: Its done. I have updated my answer. Have rewritten code. 
If you find this answer useful, please accept it and rate. If you need any additional question, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Use phps `glob()`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php for detailed documentation.

```
// Make sure $uploads has a trailing /
if(substr($uploads, -1) != '/') $uploads .= '/';

// Find all jpg files whose where name starts with "n" regardless of jpg or JPG file extension (all cases are matched)
$images = glob($uploads . 'n*.[jJ][pP]{eg,g,Eg,eG,G}', GLOB_BRACE);

var_dump($images);
```